# How can I unload a DLL loaded by Ffidl in Tcl?

Tags: dll, tcl

I need to unload a DLL that was loaded by `::ffidl::symbol` in a `::ffidl::callout` statement in Tcl.
I could use `::twapi::FreeLibrary`, but it requires the DLL's load address, which ffidl doesn't seem to expose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with unloading a library (*any* library) is that there may be dangling pointers left behind. This leaves a whole series of little landmines in your code. So ***be aware!***

To hack it, the address of the library can be obtained by using ffidl to call `Tcl_LoadFile`, which is (essentially) the Tcl API that ffidl uses to load the library in the first place, and `Tcl_FSUnloadFile`, which is a wrapper round the unload functionality you want.

```
# I'm not sure that I've got these type signatures right!
ffidl::callout Tcl_LoadFile \
    {pointer-byte pointer-utf8 pointer-byte int pointer-byte pointer-int} int \
    [ffidl::symbol tcl.dll Tcl_LoadFile]
ffidl::callout Tcl_FSUnloadFile \
    {pointer-byte int} int \
    [ffidl::symbol tcl.dll Tcl_FSUnloadFile]

set handleVar [binary format I 0]
Tcl_LoadFile 0 "theDll.dll" 0 0 0 handleVar
Tcl_FSUnloadFile 0 $handleVar
```

(Warning! I've not used ffidl before and this is untested code! I'd *actually* use [Critcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2523) instead for this, as I think it is easier to write a little glue code in embedded-C.)

Comment: If you access Tcl functionality that is exposed through the stub mechanism, use `ffidl::stubsymbol` instead of `ffidl::symbol`.